# Http Post no Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http, post

Galera, estou tentando fazer um http post para enviar um json para o servidor porém está dando um erro. Meu código está da seguinte forma

os imports

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

e aqui está meu http post

```
  onSubmit() {
console.log(this.formulario.value)

this.http
.post('https://httpbin.org/post', JSON.stringify(this.formulario.value)).pipe(
.map(res => res))
.subscribe(dados => console.log(dados))
```

}

[image: E fica constando esse erro :(, alguém poderia dar uma luz ?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se vc usar o pipe nao precisa do ponto antes do map.

```
.post('https://httpbin.org/post', JSON.stringify(this.formulario.value)).pipe
(map(res => res))
```

Comment: Thanks cara, tava me matando aqui hahah! obrigado!